# javaFX Frame image

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to use javaFX to create a window that displays images
one at a time for a certain duration of time 
I am not able to get the image to loop or display

the vbox shows up empty

This was my last attempt at getting the vbox child added to the vbox

Any with ideas? I've been stuck on this for hours

```
package digitalframe;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.*;
 import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;



public class DigitalFrame extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    final ArrayList imageList = new ArrayList<>();

    imageList.add(new ImageView("1.jpg"));
    imageList.add(new ImageView("2.jpg"));
    imageList.add(new ImageView("3.jpg"));

    // Create the label and align its contents
    final VBox vBox = new VBox();

    vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    // This is the keyframe handler.
    class ImageHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            for (int n = 0; n > imageList.size(); n++) {

                vBox.getChildren().add(new ImageView());

            }

        }

    }

    // Build the keyframe.
    Duration sec = new Duration(1000);

    ImageHandler image = new ImageHandler();

    KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(sec, image);

    // Build the time line animation.
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(keyFrame);
    timeline.setCycleCount(15);

    // Set the stage and show, and play the animation
    stage.setScene(new Scene(vBox, 250, 300));
    stage.setTitle("Animation Counter");
    stage.show();
    timeline.playFromStart();
}

 // @param args the command line arguments
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Comment: Do you ever associate your ImageViews with the Images you load?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to distinguish between [`ImageView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) and [`Image`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html). `ImageView` is the scene graph node which displays an `Image`, and `Image` is the actual image (shown by an `ImageView`). The ImageView is part of the scene graph and shows the Image it currently contains.

So, instead of creating multiple `ImageView` objects, only create one, and create `Image` objects for your images:

```
...
final List<Image> imageList = new ArrayList<>();

// create Image objects for each image
imageList.add(new Image("1.jpg"));
imageList.add(new Image("2.jpg"));
imageList.add(new Image("3.jpg"));

// Create the label and align its contents
final VBox vBox = new VBox();

vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView();   // create only one ImageView
vBox.getChildren().add(imageView);       // and add it to the scene graph
...
```

Then, in your handler, set the next image each time the handler is called:

```
@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

    imageView.setImage(imageList.get(idx++));
    if (idx >= imageList.size()) {
        idx = 0;
    }
}
```

You must not loop through all images in the handler, as the handler is called for each frame - and then, for each frame you can show the next image. Note that the `idx` variable must be declared as a field variable, since you can not use non-final local variables in a closure:

```
...
private int idx = 0;
...
```

Comment: Ok thank you , I believe that understand the image vs Imageview,  image points to the actual file and Imageview uses the image to reference the actual location

Answer (score 0):

In your loop in the keyframe handler you create a new `ImageView` that you are adding instead of using the one at the index in the list:

```
vBox.getChildren().add(imageList.get(n));
```

You probably also only want to display one image at the time. For that I would suggest to use a `StackPane` instead of a `VBox` or to remove all children from `vBox` before adding a new image.

As for looping through the images, you can loop in a while loop and increase the counter each time and use `n % imageList.size()` to calculate the current index.

Comment: ok thanks guys this all worked, i changed:   imageList.add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("5.jpg").. the image kept not displaying because it was expecting a URL   [ keywords : error URL  javafx imageview]